# Not able to luanch MySQL Installer

Tags: mysql

I downloaded MySql Installer and tried to setup on my windows desktop. But I am getting access denied error message. Details are provided below. Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\aru\Downloads\

C:\Users\aru\Downloads>mysql-installer-community-5.6.26.0.msi
Access is denied.

C:\Users\aru\Downloads>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:
Right Click and press execute as administrator.You should check the permissions given to your file too, I don't know how to do it in that command line but there is a graphical way right-clicking the installer and pressing properties.
Your problem seems to be just about permissions to your file. I hope this could help.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-permissions#1TC=windows-7
To check the permissions of a file or folder

```
Right-click the file or folder, and then click Properties.

Click the Security tab.

Click a user name or group under Group or user names.
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. I checked permissions of all groups/users on this file every group/user has full control. Any other thing I need to check.

Comment: Reason tried to run it from command prompt is not getting any error message or alert on running the msi from folder.

Answer (score 0):

My desktop is on Windows Vista.

After converting MSI installer file to exe file and running the EXE launched the installer.

Used tool from below link for converting MSI to exe.

http://www.imelfin.com/convert-msi-to-exe.html#.VeXaACVViko

Tried options in suggested in page below before considering the other option.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-using-installer.html